# Apache Spark SQL query and DataFrame as reference data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark DataFrames:

`cities` DataFrame with the following column:

```
city
-----
London
Austin
```

`bigCities` DataFrame with the following column:

```
name
------
London
Cairo
```

I need to transform DataFrame `cities` and add an additional Boolean column there: `bigCity` Value of this column must be calculated based on the following condition `"cities.city IN bigCities.name"`

I can do this in the following way(with a static bigCities collection):

```
cities.createOrReplaceTempView("cities")

var resultDf = spark.sql("SELECT city, CASE WHEN city IN ['London', 'Cairo'] THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS bigCity FROM cities")
```

but I don't know how to replace the static bigCities collection `['London', 'Cairo']` with `bigCities` DataFrame in the query. I want to use `bigCities` as the reference data in the query.

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: You can use left join between these two datasets on `cities.city` and `bigCities.name` column. If value coming from right table is null in the result, you can flag it with `false` with `withColumn` and `when` function on Spark.

Comment: Other solution also possible, you can take unique values of `bigCities.name` column into a list. Afterwards, you can filter or flag your `city` Dataset with `isin` function of `Column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use collect_list() on the the bigCities table. Check this out

```
scala> val df_city = Seq(("London"),("Austin")).toDF("city")
df_city: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [city: string]

scala> val df_bigCities = Seq(("London"),("Cairo")).toDF("name")
df_bigCities: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string]

scala> df_city.createOrReplaceTempView("cities")

scala> df_bigCities.createOrReplaceTempView("bigCities")

scala> spark.sql(" select city, case when array_contains((select collect_list(name) from bigcities),city) then 'Y' else 'N' end as bigCity from cities").show(false)
+------+-------+
|city  |bigCity|
+------+-------+
|London|Y      |
|Austin|N      |
+------+-------+


scala>
```

If the dataset is big, you can use collect_set which will be more efficient.

```
scala> spark.sql(" select city, case when array_contains((select collect_set(name) from bigcities),city) then 'Y' else 'N' end as bigCity from cities").show(false)
+------+-------+
|city  |bigCity|
+------+-------+
|London|Y      |
|Austin|N      |
+------+-------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it a problem for Spark and the proposed approach that `bigcities` DataFrame can be quite big? Let's say based on 9GB CSV file

Comment: the file can be big but you will be passing only one column to collect_list() function. Also I suppose there will be duplicates, so you can use collect_set() instead of collect_list which will be efficient.. let me update the answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
val df = cities.join(bigCities, $"name".equalTo($"city"), "leftouter").
                withColumn("bigCity", when($"name".isNull, "N").otherwise("Y")).
                drop("name")
```